# weird difference between int pointer and float pointer

Tags: c, pointers, floating-point, int, printf

please see my codes below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct _node
{
int a;
char *s;
}Node, *nodePtr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *str = "string"; /*str points to satic storage area*/
Node nd;
nodePtr pNode = NULL;
size_t offset_of_s = offsetof(Node,s);

nd.a = 1;
nd.s = str;

pNode = &nd;

    /*Get addr of s, cast it to a different data types pointer, then de-reference it*/

/*this works, print "string"*/
printf("%s\n", *(int*)((char*)pNode + offset_of_s));

/*this sucks, print (null)*/
printf("%s\n", *(float*)((char*)pNode + offset_of_s));

return 0;
}
```

i attempt to get the address of the **s** member of the Node structure, **cast** it to a data types not less than 4 bytes(**4** byte is the width of a **pointer** on my machine), then de-reference the pointer as a argument to **printf**.

i do think the outcome of two printfs should be the **same**, but the second one displays **"(null)"** .

float and int have the same byte width on my machine,  is the **internal different representation** of the two types that cause this ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program invokes undefined behavior because the types of the arguments to `printf()` are not what printf expects. There is no way to predict the outcome by looking at the source code.

C99-TC3, `§7.19.6.1/9`

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

However, if you are interested in the reason the behavior you've observed is as it is, it's likely that your compiler is one of those that pass floating-point values to printf() in the floating-point CPU registers. (GNU and CLang do that, for example). The second call to printf placed the dereferenced value in a floating-point register, but `printf`, seeing the `%s` conversion specifier, looked at the register where a `char*` would have been passed, likely a general-purpose register, which happened to be zero in your case.

PS: Here's what GCC 4.6.1 makes out of it on my linux

```
main:
    pushq   %rbx
    leal    .LC0(%rip), %ebx
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %ebx, %edx
    movl    $1, %edi
    movq    $.LC0, 8(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    __printf_chk

    movd    %ebx, %xmm0
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    movl    $1, %eax
    unpcklps    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtps2pd    %xmm0, %xmm0 # this is where your value went
    call    __printf_chk     # is NOT gonna read from xmm0!

    addq    $16, %rsp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```

Same story with clang 2.9

```
    ...
    movl    $.L.str, %ebx
    xorb    %al, %al
    movl    $.L.str1, %edi     # .L.str1 is your format "%s\n"
    movl    $.L.str, %esi      # .L.str  is your static "string"
    callq   printf

    movd    %ebx, %xmm0        # your value is in xmm0 again
    cvtss2sd    %xmm0, %xmm0   # promoted to double, but still in xmm0
    movb    $1, %al
    movl    $.L.str1, %edi
    callq   printf             # printf has no idea
```

Comment: +1, yes on the UB, but the reason for the output of `(null)` has nothing to do with the floating-point registers—in variadiac functions, `float`s get promoted to `doubles` as part of the default argument promotions.  The promoted `double` value of course has no relation to the original pointer; that the first four bytes of it happen to come out to NULL is a lucky coincidence.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield added assembly output

Comment: Good point.  But the `float` to `double` promotion in variadic functions is often a source of confusion and/or bugs with people trying to do quirky things with `printf`/`scanf`.

Comment: @cubbi thank you for the deep explanation, but how to understand the assembly code, is there a manual for me to read first ?

Answer (score 2):

Your expectations are apparently based on your belief that variadic arguments of variadic functions are passed to those functions in some specific way. This is already very implementation-dependent, so from the point of the formal C language your experiments already make very little sense.

I'd guess that you expect the variadic arguments to be copied to the "variadic argument array" of some sort (stack frame?) as blocks of raw memory, regardless of their type-specific semantics. For this reason you apparently believe that an `int` argument should be passed in exactly the same way as a `float` argument since both types happen to have the same size on your platform.

This assumption is totally unfounded and incorrect. What is actually passed to `printf` in this case is the *values* of the arguments in question, and since these values have completely different type-specific semantics, they can easily be passed in completely different ways. Needless to say, the behavior of your code is undefined for more reasons than one.

One basic thing that you need to understand in this case is that it is completly impossible to pass a `float` value as a variadic parameter of a variadic function. All `float` values are automatically promoted to `double` values before passing, as required by the language specification. (The same applies to `char` and `short` values, which are always promoted to `int` first.) Considering that in your case the `float` value was obtained by reinterpreting memory occupied by a pointer object, and then promoted to `double`, it is not surprising that the results you observe make no sense whatsoever.

Another basic thing that you need to understand that reinterpreting memory occupied by an object of one type and an object of another type is no allowed by C language (in a sense that the resultant behavior is undefined). You are not allowed to reinterpret memory occupied by a pointer object as an `int` object. And this is exactly what you are attempting to do. Even the first of your `printf`s, which allegedly "works as expected", does so only by accident.

Comment: if reinterpreting memory occupied by an object of one type as an object of another type is not allowed in C, then how come the cast works, say, **(char*)pNode** in my code, i just reinterpreted a pointer to **Node** as a **char** pointer to perform my pointer arithmetic

Comment: @Tracy: No, you didn't. When you do `(char*) pNode` you *did not reinterpret* `pNode` as `char *`. You *converted* `pNode` to `char *` type. There's huge difference between *conversion* and *reinterpretation*. Conversions are fine. Reinterpretations are not. In order to *reinterpret* `pNode` as `char *` you'd have to do this: `*(char **) &pNode`. This last example is *reinterpretation*. See the difference? And reinterpretation is generally not allowed. It leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tracy: Also, there are different levels of "not allowed" in C. There are so called *constraint violations*, i.e. compiler errors. And there are *undefined behaviors* and stuff like that. Basically, some "not allowed" are supposed to be caught by the compiler, while some others "not allowed" you are supposed to catch by yourself. In your example, if your replace `(char*) pNode` conversion with `*(char **) &pNode` reinterpretation chances are the code will still "work" as it did before. Yet, the behavior of is still undefined, so it is "not allowed" in that sense.

Comment: is __conversion__ like casts other than __reinterpret_cast__  , __reinterpretation__ like __reinterpret_cast__ in c++ ? Does it mean __reinterpretation__ is allowed in C++ with full language support ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The internal representation of [a float](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/manual/html_node/Representation-of-floating-point-numbers.html) and [an integer](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html) in binary is vastly different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the address, use the "%p" format specifier with printf().  It's been in C since K&R2 and maybe before.